# Favicon Not Appearing with ExpressJS Setup

Tags: node.js, express, favicon

I am using the ExpressJS native packages, `serve-favicon` to load my favicon to my server, but I can't seem to get the favicon to appear in my tab icon despite setting up my code as documented. Do I need to add something to my HTML to have it work correctly? Is there any reason why my code wouldn't work? Provided below if my `app.js`

**Favicon Code:**

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
```

**Favicon File:**

```
/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/app-name/public/favicon.ico
```

**Full `app.js` code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//External Packages
var hbs = require('express-hbs');
var passport = require('passport');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var morgan = require('morgan');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var csp = require('helmet-csp');
var csrf = require('csurf');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');

var controllers = require('./app/controllers/routes');
var hbsHelper = require('./views/helpers/hbs-helper')(hbs);

//Port Setting
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Set Morgan as Logger
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//Set Helmet for Security
app.use(helmet());
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.use(csp({
    directives: {
        ...
        *directives*
        ...
    }
}));

//Extract POST Data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Cookie Parser
app.use(cookieParser());


//Session Cookie Config
var sess = {
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: process.env.REDIS_ENDPOINT || 'localhost',
        port: 6379
    }),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || *secret*,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        domain: process.env.DOMAIN_NAME || *local*
    }
}

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
    app.set('trust proxy', 1)
    sess.cookie.secure = true
};

//Set Session Cookie
app.use(session(sess));

//Temporary Robots.txt
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if ('/robots.txt' == req.url) {
        res.type('text/plain')
        res.send("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /");
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

app.use(flash());

//Passport Initialization
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


//Set CSRF for Form Tokens
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals._csrf = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});

//Handlebars View Engine
app.engine('hbs', hbs.express4({
    partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials',
     onCompile: function(exhbs, source, filename) {
        var options;
        options = {preventIndent: true};
    return exhbs.handlebars.compile(source, options);
  }
}));


//Public Directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico'))
//Load Favicon
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

//Webpack Compiled JS
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

//Routing
app.use(controllers);

//Port Listening
app.listen(port);
console.log('access at port:' + port);
```

Comment: Make sure that your favico is available on correct path.

Comment: As Batman says (log the result of `path.join` to be sure), then try declaring `app.use(favicon(...` before other `.use`, in case one of them catches the request and doesn't call `next` as it can't serve it. (As their NPM page says by the way: _Typically this middleware will come very early in your stack (maybe even first) to avoid processing any other middleware if we already know the request is for `/favicon.ico`._)

Comment: The `console.log` renders `/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/app-name/public/favicon.ico` which is the same `path.join` as the favicon. Would the dimensions of the file have any impact?